# Org-export: How to include a pregenerated HTML file when exporting org to HTML?

Tags: org-export

I'm rewriting my personal home page as an org-file that I export to HTML.  In this HTML document, I'd like to include the content of some pregenerated HTML fragments stored in other files (my list of publications as generated by `bibtex2html`).

Here is an example document:

```
* My personal home page
** Articles
[insert HTML file with list of articles here]

** Posters
[insert HTML file with list of posters here]
```

I tried using `#+INCLUDE:` but that escapes all HTML and hence shows the HTML source in the resulting web page not the rendered HTML fragment.

I also tried the following

```
#+BEGIN_HTML
#+INCLUDE: "file.html"
#+END_HTML
```

but the `#+INCLUDE` directive is not interpreted inside the HTML block.

It seems like there should be an easy way to achieve this but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: First I would look into defining an appropriate `:html-preamble` or a `:html-postamble`, maybe using a `#+SETUPFILE:` to invoke it. Another approach would be to add a `org-export-html-final-hook`, possibly with help from `auto-insert`.

Comment: Thanks @BrianZ for these suggestions.  Unfortunately, `:html-preamble` and `:html-postamble` won't work because I need to insert the HTML fragments in the middle of the file not at the beginning and end. `org-export-html-final-hook` is mentioned in a ChangeLog but I can't find its definition anywhere in source.  `apropos` also doesn't know it.  I'll post a feature request for a verbatim flag for `#+INCLUDE`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cf. the second paragraph in the Org manual on `#+INCLUDE` you can
archive what you want using (Org v9 syntax)

```
#+INCLUDE: "file.html" export html
```

For Org v8 you would write `#+INCLUDE: "file.html" html`.

This inserts is a block and requires org-mode v8.3 or higher.

> ## 11.4 Include files
>
> During export, you can include the content of another file.  For
>   example, to include your ‘.emacs’ file, you could use:
>
> ```
>  #+INCLUDE: "~/.emacs" src emacs-lisp
> ```
>
> The first parameter names the the file to include.  **The optional second
>   and third parameter specify the markup (i.e., ‘example’ or ‘src’)**, and,
>   if the markup is ‘src’, the language for formatting the contents.

Comment: As I said in the original question, this doesn't work.  It escapes all HTML such that I see the HTML source but not the rendered version of the HTML in the output file.

Comment: Ok, it works but only in org mode version 8.3 (unstable).  Perhaps you could add that crucial piece of information to the solution.  Thank you.

Comment: Same prob with latest org from github 8.3.4, I try to include html code from http://www.htmlcommentbox.com/ to enable comments.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using org-mode 8.2.10

Although I was expecting `#+INCLUDE: "path" html` to work, it was
formatting the file contents in `<p>` tags.

To work around this problem, I used an sh code block:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :exports results :results value html
#!/bin/bash
/bin/cat ~/path/to/file.html
#+END_SRC
```